# PHP code to create unique 3 digit combinations from array with following conditions

Tags: php, arrays

**Conditions:**

> 1. Starting digit should not be 0
> 2. Succeeding digits should be greater than preceding numbers.
> 3. The last digit can be 0
> 4. The middle digit should not be 0

We have succeeded in satisfying the first two conditions but because of the contradiction between second and third condition, I am not able to get the expected output.

For example,
The input 1234 gives output:

```
123
124
134
234
```

For the digits `12340`, the output should be:

```
123
124
134
234
120
120
140
230
240
340
```

But it isn't working with what I have done.

The code:

```
<?
function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
    if (empty($items)) {
        $return = array($perms);
    }  else {
        $return = array();
        for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
             $newitems = $items;
             $newperms = $perms;
         list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
             array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
             $return = array_merge($return, pc_permute($newitems, $newperms));
         }
    }
    return $return;
}

// example
$chars = array('1', '2', '3','4','0');
$output = pc_permute($chars);
$a=count($output);
for ($i = 0; $i<count($output);$i++) {
  for ($j = 0; $j < 3;$j++){
   $c[$i] = $c[$i].$output[$i][$j];
 }
}
$arr = array_unique($c);
$last = end(array_keys($arr));
$n=0;
for($i = 0;$i <= $last;$i++) {
  if(!empty($arr[$i])){
  $temp = $arr[$i];
  $d = str_split($temp);
  $e = end(array_keys($d));
  $flag = 0;
  for($j = 0;$j < (count($d)-1); $j++) {
  if(($d[$j] < $d[$j+1] && $d[0] != 0)) {
   $flag = 1; 
  }
  else {
   $flag = 0;
   break;
  } 
 }
 if($flag == 1) {
   echo $temp;
   echo "<br>";
   $n++;
  }

 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a homework/assignment question?

Comment: "Conditions" should be clarified. Do you have to use all the digits in the array? If so and the array contains `0` then due to conditions **2** and **3** the problem have no solution and the resulting output should be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should deviate the following steps for your program based on the rules:

1. Due to rule 2 you can remove duplicates
2. Due to rule 2 you can sort the input
3. Due to rule 1, 3 and 4 you can move 0 to the end of the array, if present

If that is respected you can then iterate over the input array with three foreach loops, that permutate the succeeding numbers with the preceding ones. Because it is sorted in the correct order all rules will be respected automatically.

The comments explain what is done in each step.

```
$input = [0, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4];
$results = [];

//Remove duplicates, necessary for rule 2
$input = array_unique($input);  

//Sort Numbers, necessary for rule 2
sort($input);  

// Mark 0 as the greates number, so it can only appear at the end. Necessary for rule 1, 3 and 4
if ($input[0] === 0) {
    $input[] = array_shift($input);
}

$inputCount = count($input);
for( $i = 0; $i < $inputCount - 2; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < $inputCount - 1; $j++) {
        for ($k = $j + 1; $k < $inputCount; $k++) {
            $results[] = $input[$i] . $input[$j] . $input[$k];
        }
    }
}

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: [Running example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d00e4d0d8f62e596f1d921ae3c8717c45396782)